# What's different between async { ... AsyncAdd ... } and async { ... do AsyncAdd ... }?

Tags: f#

In the following code, both `do! ag.AsyncAdd (Some i)` or `ag.AsyncAdd (Some i)` (in the function `enqueue()`) work. What's the difference between them? It seems `do! ...` will make enqueuing and dequeuing calls more mixed? How?

```
open FSharpx.Control

let test () =
    let ag = new BlockingQueueAgent<int option>(500)

    let enqueue() = async { 
        for i = 1 to 15 do 
            // ag.AsyncAdd (Some i) // works too
            do! ag.AsyncAdd (Some i) 
            printfn "=> %d" i }

    async {
        do! [ for i = 1 to 10 do yield enqueue() ] 
            |> Async.Parallel |> Async.Ignore
        for i = 1 to 5 do ag.Add None
    } |> Async.Start

    let rec dequeue() =
        async {
            let! m = ag.AsyncGet()
            match m with
            | Some v ->
                printfn "<= %d" v
                return! dequeue()
            | None -> 
                printfn "Done" 
        }

    [ for i = 1 to 5 do yield dequeue() ] 
    |> Async.Parallel |> Async.Ignore |> Async.RunSynchronously
    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [FSharpx source code](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Async/blob/a1a68c5bd2568b343b5c37f4b221d93cdf3a83b6/src/FSharpx.Async/BlockingQueueAgent.fs) (see comments):

```ml
    /// Asynchronously adds item to the queue. The operation ends when
    /// there is a place for the item. If the queue is full, the operation
    /// will block until some items are removed.
    member x.AsyncAdd(v:'T, ?timeout) = 
      agent.PostAndAsyncReply((fun ch -> AsyncAdd(v, ch)), ?timeout=timeout)
```

When you do not use do!, you do not block enqueue thread in case if queue is full (500 items in queue as you state in constructor). So, when you changed loops to higher number, you spammed MailboxProcessor queue with messages (behind the scene FSharpx uses MailboxProcessor - check docs for this class) of type AsyncAdd from all iterations of all enqueue thread. This slows down another operation, agent.Scan:

```ml
        and fullQueue() = 
            agent.Scan(fun msg ->
              match msg with 
              | AsyncGet(reply) -> Some(dequeueAndContinue(reply))
              | _ -> None )
```

- because you have in queue a lot of AsyncAdd and AsyncGet.

In case, when you put do! before AsyncAdd, you enqueue threads will be blocked at moment when there are 500 items in queue and no additional messages would be generated for MailboxProcessor, thus agent.Scan will work fast. When dequeue thread takes an item and the number of them becomes 499, new enqueue thread awaiks and adds new item and then goes to next iteration of a loop, put new AsyncAdd message into MailboxProcessor and again, goes to sleep till moment of dequeue. Thus, MailboxProcessor is not spammed with messages AsyncAdd of all iterations of one enqueue thread. Note: queue of items and queue of MailboxProcessor messages are different queues.

Comment: Your answer seems the best answer for the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652524/fire-and-no-wait-without-do-vs-fire-and-await-do-got-huge-difference-perfo. Can you post this answer to the question?

Comment: BTW, changing the async call `AsyncAdd` to the synchronous `Add` takes 8 seconds. It shouldn't have the spamming issue. And there are more enqueue than dequeue. Why it's slower? Someone said the  `MailBoxProcesser.Post` is faster than `PostAndAsyncReply`.

Comment: Add is implemented as agent.Post - so it just put message Add into MailboxProcessor queue and enqueue thread (thread which performs iterations with enqueue) do this for all iterations - it does not wait for empty spot in item queue. The call is still asynchronous from perspective of enqueue thread. MailboxProcessor thread will hold Add message in queue till the moment when in item queue there will be a space. Thus, spamming is still happens. So Add is kind of AsyncAdd without do!  but a little lighter

Comment: If you have time, you can write some experiment in F# console app with mailbox processor - taking FSharpx.Control code from github (type Agent == MailboxProcessor) and add some printlns there or go step by step. [MailboxProcessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/control.mailboxprocessor%5B'msg%5D-class-%5Bfsharp%5D) has property CurrentQueueLength - this is queue of messages. You can then analyze the length and its impact on performace. It is curious experiment. Then you can put results here or to other question.

Answer (score 6):

Inside any F# computation expression, any keyword that ends with `!` tends to mean "Handle this one specially, according to the rules of this block". E.g., in an `async { }` block, the `let!` keyword means "await the result, then assign the result to this variable" and the `do!` keyword means "await this asynchronous operation, but throw away the result and don't assign it to anything". If you *don't* use a `do!` keyword, then you are *not* awaiting the result of that operation.

So with a `do!` keyword inside your `enqueue` function, you are doing the following fifteen times:

- Kick off an `AsyncAdd` operation
- Wait for it to complete
- print "=> 1" (or 2, or 3...)

**Without** a `do!` keyword, you are doing the following:

- Kick off fifteen `AsyncAdd` operations as fast as possible
- After kicking each one off, print "=> 1" (or 2, or 3...)

It sounds like you don't yet fully understand how F#'s computation expressions work behind the scenes. I recommend reading Scott Wlaschin's excellent site to gain more understanding: first https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/ and then https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/computation-expressions.html so that when you read the second series of articles, you're building on a bit of existing knowledge.

Comment: I see. So with `do!` it's like `await` in C#. In the question above, with or without `do!` should have similar performance? Even it prints more enqueue during the first half and more dequeue is printed later. However, my testing shows with `do!` the code runs with higher CPU then without `do!` (after change the loops very large)?

Comment: F#'s `async` expressions are hard to benchmark correctly, as the internal async mechanisms will be using a significant percentage of your CPU that will throw off your benchmarks. The general advice usually given is to use `async` for I/O-bound code, not for CPU-bound code. So don't think about "is it more efficient to use `do!` or not?". Instead, you should be asking yourself whether it's more *correct* to `await` this asynchronous process you're kicking off. (Answer: yes, usually.)

Comment: I changed the loops to larger numbers and commented out the `printfn`. It took 17.5 seconds without `do!`. And it took less a second (**17 seconds** vs **340 milliseconds**) after added `do!`. Why? BTW, I tried to run the enqueue/dequeue in parallel using `async`. What's the best approach to do it if not using async?